# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server incorrect syntax near . ''

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to create table in MS SQL server management 17 using php.

my query is:

```
                            $mid=$row['MASTER_ID'];
                            echo $mid;
                            $table_solution="CREATE TABLE Q_MASTERID_'$mid'_Solution(
                                            MASTER_ID INT ,  
                                            PRODUCT_NAME varchar(255),
                                            CUSTOMER_NAME varchar(255),
                                            Q_TEMP_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                                            Q_DESC nvarchar(600) NULL,
                                            Q_CATEGORY nvarchar(255)  NULL,
                                            Q_SUB_CATEGORY nvarchar(255) NULL,
                                            SCOPE nvarchar(255) NULL 
                                            ) ON PRIMARY"; 

                            $solution_alter="ALTER TABLE Q_MASTERID_'$mid'_Solution ADD Q_ID AS CONCAT ('A',CAST(Q_TEMP_ID AS VARCHAR(100)))PERSISTED" ;

                             $res=sqlsrv_query($con,$table_solution) or die("Couldn't execute create query".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                            $res1=sqlsrv_query($con,$solution_alter) or die("Couldn't execute alter query");
```

i am getting following error :

> Couldn't execute create queryArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ''. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ''. ) )

if i remove $mid in create query im getting following error

> Couldn't execute create queryArray ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 156 [code] => 156 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRIMARY'. ) )

i want to add dynamic variable called $mid while creating table "CREATE TABLE Q_MASTERID_'$mid'_Solution" 
help me to resolve this...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying for:

```
CREATE TABLE Q_MASTERID_Solution (
    MASTER_ID INT ,  
    PRODUCT_NAME varchar(255),
    CUSTOMER_NAME varchar(255),
    Q_TEMP_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Q_DESC nvarchar(600) NULL,
    Q_CATEGORY nvarchar(255)  NULL,
    Q_SUB_CATEGORY nvarchar(255) NULL,
    COPE nvarchar(255) NULL ,
    Q_ID AS ( CONCAT('A', CAST(Q_TEMP_ID AS VARCHAR(100))) ) PERSISTED
) ON "default"
```

I see no reason to include the `ON "default"` because that is the default partition scheme if none is specified.  If you do specify one, then you need to specify an existing one.

You can include the definition of `q_id` in the name.

It is a really bad practice to create multiple tables with identical schemas.  Instead, include `MASTER_ID` as a column in the table and filter for each master id.

Comment: $mid=$row['MASTER_ID'];
$table_solution="CREATE TABLE Q_MASTERID_'$mid'_Solution                         this is what my problem is i want to create dynamic table which value is getting from $mid variable.

Comment: @anupriya . . . Don't do it.  Add rows to an existing table and remove them when you are done.